# General form of $\mathbb{Q}\otimes M$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Compute the following tensor products (as $\mathbb{Z}$ modules):

1. $\mathbb{Q}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/(n)$.
2. $\mathbb{Q}\otimes\mathbb{Q}$.
3. $\mathbb{Q}\otimes\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.
4. $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} $.
5. $\mathbb{Q}\otimes M$ where $M$ is any $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Here is what I have so far:

1. It is clear that $\mathbb{Q}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/(n)$ is not cyclic of order at most $n$ (but what is it?).
2. The generators of this tensor product look like:
   $$\frac{p}{m}\otimes\frac{q}{n}=pq\left(\frac{1}{m}\otimes\frac{1}{n}\right) $$
   where $m,n,p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$, $m,n\neq 0$. Honestly, I can't recognize a usual group with the following property.
3. $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a module where each element has finite order, and so we can expect that every element in the tensor product to have finite order.
4. My guess for this one is that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ but only intuitively.
5. Since $M$ is any module, what can we do?

I don't need a precise answer, just hints, except for the last part. What can we do when $M$ is any $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints to get you started:

- For $\Bbb Q \otimes \Bbb Z/(n)$, note that
  $$
  q \otimes k = n\frac qn \otimes k = \frac qn \otimes nk = \frac qn \otimes 0
  $$
- For $p,q \in \Bbb Q$, we have $p \otimes q = (pq) \otimes 1$
- For $p \in \Bbb Q$ and $[q] \in \Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$, note that $$
  p \otimes [\frac ab] = (b \frac pb) \otimes [\frac ab] = \frac pb
   \otimes [a] = 0$$
- Does the same trick work for 4?
- Look for the common pattern in parts 1,2,3.